# How to sort x and y axis in line charts in flutter

Tags: android, sorting, charts, flutter

I am having a hard time displaying a line chart in flutter using the official charts plugin.

the problem is the sorting, I can't find a way to sort the y-axis only. because my x-axis comes sorted ( from a REST API ) so the plugin displays it as it is so I get a weird y-axis with ticks starting like 5 - 10 - 7 - 1

```
new LineChart(
    lines: [
        new Line<Kpi, String, num>(
            data: data,
            xFn: (clickData) => (clickData as Kpi).key,
            yFn: (clickData) => (clickData as Kpi).nbr,
            xAxis: new ChartAxis(
                offset: 0.0,
                hideLine: false,
            ),
        ),
    ],
)
```

the data format is simple  :

```
[
    {
        key : "key1",
        nbr : 5
    },
    {
        key : "key2",
        nbr : 2
    },
]
```

To be more precise, I want to sort the x Axis based on Dates & the y Axis based on numbers then place the points for each couple on the chart body. 
what I get right now is something like this :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but I was looking for the same solution and thought somebody else might want to know what I did to solve the problem. **You can't sort the data in the chart itself; you have to sort the data that comes in from your API first.**

I'm using Firestore for my data, so when getting the collection, I did the following:

`Firestore.instance.collection('example').orderBy('time', descending: false).snapshots()`